# Using pri files to reduce compiler time in Qt when building several projects

Tags: performance, qt, module, compilation, qmake

I organized my projects contains apps and tests pro files and libs pri files as below:

```
root
├── apps
│   ├── mainapp
│   │   ├── mainapp.pro
│   │   └── other mainapp files...
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── app2.pro
│   │   └── other app2 files...
│   └── allApps.pro
├── libs
│   ├── lib1
│   │   ├── lib1.pri
│   │   └── other lib1 files...
│   └── lib2
│       ├── lib2.pri
│       └── other lib2 files...
├── tests
│   ├── test1
│   │   ├── test1.pro
│   │   └── other test1 files...
│   ├── test2
│   │   ├── test2.pro
│   │   └── other test2 files...
│   └── allTests.pro
└── all.pro
```

*all.pro* is a subdir project containing *allApps.pro* and *allTests.pro* containing themself all apps and tests pro files.

Library *pri* files are library included by the apps and the tests project.

When build *all.pro* with *qmake* / *make*, my libraries are compiled for each app and test which is very time consuming...

Is there a way that the files included in my libs are compiled only once?

Thank you for your help!

#### Edit

I precise that I use *pri* files for lib because it's the only way I found to make my library code debuggable, and where change are taken in account when rebuilding the project.

Comment: Awesome! It now works exactly like I want :-)

Comment: I add an edit about my needs to debug and to automatically relink and you can just copy past your usefull comment so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree does not agree with your narrative: there are no .pri files anywhere in your tree. IOW: You've answered your own question: your libraries should be .pro files and produce a static library, not .pri files :)

Static libraries are fully debuggable. You can compile Qt as a static library and debug into it, for example.

> I have another problem: when I change something in the lib, the app doesn't automatically link it

You need to make the application dependent on the library. Add the library to the `PRE_TARGETDEPS` in the application's .pro file. You also need to set up the proper dependency in the top-level subdirs project, to ensure that the libraries are always built prior to the projects that use them. Add, for example

```
apps/mainapp.depends += libs/lib1.
```